# Portfolio simulation using Cholesky decomposition

Tags: r, montecarlo

I do a MC simulation of a portfolio with 4 assets (Bond, equity, equity, cash market)
I use monthly steps and my simulation horizon is 10 years i.e. 120 steps. My final goal is to compute the yearly expected shortfall, i.e. taking the worst 5% of the Portfolio Returns.

The simulation seems to be ok - at the first glance. However, I have the impression the drift dominates the process over time, so my expected shortfall is even positive for the long end. Also the expected shortfall eventually decreases when I increase the weights for equity. This is also true when I set the expected return for each asset to zero and hence the increased risk should drag the expected shortfall down. 
I expect a bug in my code but can't see it. Any advice highly appreciated!

```
#maturity in years
maturity <- 10
#Using monthly steps
nsteps <- maturity*12
dt <-  maturity / nsteps
#number of assets
nAssets = 4
#number of simulations
nTrails = 10000

#expected return p.a. for each asset, stored in vector BM.mu
BM.mu <- rep(NA,nAssets)
BM.mu[1] <- 0.0072
BM.mu[2] <- 0.0365
BM.mu[3] <- 0.04702
BM.mu[4] <- 0.0005

#defining variable size
simulated.Returns   <- array(NA,    dim = c(nsteps+1, nTrails, nAssets))
cumulative.PortReturns  <- matrix(rep(NA,nsteps*nTrails), nrow = nsteps, ncol = nTrails)
ES  <- rep(NA, maturity)

#defining my monthly correlation and covariance matrix
corr_matrix <- matrix(c(1.000000000, -0.05081574, -0.07697585,  0.0051,
            -0.050815743,  1.00000000,  0.80997805, -0.3540,
            -0.076975850,  0.80997805,  1.00000000, -0.3130,
            0.005095699, -0.35365332, -0.31278506,  1.0000), nrow = 4, ncol = 4)

cov_matrix <- matrix(c(1.44e-04, -2.20e-05, -3.86e-05,  8.44e-08,
            -2.20e-05,  1.30e-03,  1.22e-03, -1.76e-05,
            -3.86e-05,  1.22e-03,  1.75e-03, -1.81e-05,
            8.44e-08, -1.76e-05, -1.81e-05,  1.90e-06), nrow = 4, ncol = 4)

#defining my portfolio weights
port.weights <- c(0.72, 0.07, 0.07, 0.14)

#performing cholesky decomposition
R <- (chol(corr_matrix))

#generating standard-normal, random variables
x <- array(rnorm(nsteps*nTrails*nAssets), c(nsteps*nTrails,nAssets))

#generating correlated standard-normal, random variables
ep <- x %*% R

#defining the drift 
drift <- BM.mu - 0.5 * diag(cov_matrix) 

#generating asset paths
temp = array(exp(as.vector(drift %*% t(dt)) + t(ep *sqrt(diag(cov_matrix)))), c(nAssets,nsteps,nTrails))

for(i in 2:nsteps) temp[,i,] = temp[,i,] * temp[,(i-1),] 

#changing dimension of the array temp from dim(nAssets, nsteps, nTrails) to dim(nsteps, nAssets, nTrails)
simulated.Returns <- aperm(temp,c(2,1,3))

#computing portfolio returns for each simulation (nTrails). To do this, each step is weighted with "port.weights"
#Since I generate continuous returns, I first transform them into discrete, multiply with weights and then transform back into continuous.
for (z in 1:nTrails) {
for (i in 1:nsteps) cumulative.PortReturns[i,z] = log(1+((exp(simulated.Returns[i,,z]-1)-1) %*% port.weights))
}

#Finally I compute the monthly expected shortfall (5%-level) by taking the average of the 5% worst portfolio yields
#I do steps of 12 as I calculate the ES at the end of each year
z = 0
for (i in seq(12, nsteps, by = 12 )) {
z = z + 1 
ES[z]   <- mean(sort(cumulative.PortReturns[i,]) [1:(0.05*nTrails)])
}

#plotting a sample of simulated portfolio returns
#library(QRM)
plot(as.timeSeries(cumulative.PortReturns[,1:100]), plot.type = 'single')
```

Comment: I'm unsure of the impact of your output compared to your expectations, but covariance matrices (and, consequently, correlation matrices) must be symmetric by definition. `corr_matrix` in the code above is not symmetric.

Comment: Can you `set.seed` and show `ES` output with commentary? Its not clear exactly what output you are seeing or why it is suspect.

Comment: I don't think the generation of the correlated normal variables is a problem, but note that R provides `cov2cor` so you really only need the covariance matrix specified. Also `mvrnorm` from library `MASS` is widely used to generate correlated random variables.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, you have defined `BM.mu` to be the annual expected return for each asset. However, you are simulating each sample path using monthly rather than annual steps. This then needs to be incorporated in your `drift` variable by scaling `BM.mu` to the expected monthly return accordingly:

```
#defining the drift
drift <- BM.mu/12 - 0.5 * diag(cov_matrix)
```

Without this, you are computing the `drift` value using an *annual* expected return value and a *monthly* covariance matrix. This is resulting in a larger drift than you expect, which would impact on the results you are seeing.

Comment: I believe this is why `drift` is multiplied by `dt=1/12`, but yes the covariance  would need to be stated in annualized terms, which if it is, there is a missing `sqrt(dt)`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far. I used monthly data to compute the covariance matrix. So I thought "scaling down" the covariance is not necessary. I also changed my code and use the covariance matrix only. Now, expected shortfall figures seem to make sense, i.e. ES increases when shifting weights to riskier assets. Thanks for that hint! I will update my code later. However, still have the problem with my drift (expected portfolio value at the end of 10 year) beeing too high. The above portfolio has an annual return of 1.11%, but I have values of 18%

Comment: I believe the drift has to be: drift <- BM.mu/12 + 0.5 * diag(cov_matrix), am I right? Did you make any progress on the code?